# Author pane block

Tags: blocks

In my project I am working on user profile. to display user info I am using [Author Pane](https://www.drupal.org/project/author_pane) module, which provide a block and showing information. But this block not display on other pages of site. How to change configuration of author block to display on any page?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to configure your 'Author Pane' settings as follows.

If you want to display block on all node types make sure to select all node type checkboxes (under Block Title Field).

[image]

and make sure to configure Visibility Settings of the Block.

If you want to display this block on all pages. make sure to check 'All pages except those listed'

I've tested this and working fine. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Hey Krishna thanks for your great effort... its working for me what you post. but I am facing one more issue is -> Author pane not display on some particular pages of my site like www.example.com/messages. (using private message module for messages).